# Populate UIActionSheet Buttons With NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to pull up an UIActionSheet to show all the accounts that are currently signed into Settings for Twitter.  I get the NSArray of all accounts matching type Twitter and then run this code:

```
UIActionSheet *chooseaccount = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose Account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]--; i++) {
    [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i]];
}
[chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
chooseaccount.cancelButtonIndex = arrayOfAccounts.count;
chooseaccount showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
```

However, I get the error "Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed"

Any suggestions for getting the UIActionSheet to show all the UserNames of Twitter accounts?

UPDATE:
After going through several suggestions, I have changed the code to this:

```
-(void)twitteraccess {
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                                  ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                  completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
        if (granted == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"Granted");

            NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                        accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
            if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"%i", [arrayOfAccounts count]);

                if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 1) {
                    NSLog(@"Greaterthan1");
                    UIActionSheet *chooseaccount = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Choose Account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]; i++) {

                        ACAccount * account = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i];
                        [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:account.username];
                        NSLog(@"%@", account.username);
                    }

                    [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
                    chooseaccount.cancelButtonIndex = arrayOfAccounts.count;

                    [chooseaccount showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
                }
                else {

                }

            }
        }
        else {
            if(error.code == 6){
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(alertmessagetwitter)
                                       withObject:nil
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];                }
        }
    }];
}
```

The action sheet does appear, but it takes about 25 seconds to show up.

Comment: You should have used fast enumeration instead of this ugly looking loop     `for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]--; i++) {
    [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i]];
}`

Comment: `for(NSString *title in arrayOfAccounts){ [ [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:title]; }`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya if I do that, what would be the NSString in the array to get the username?  `(
    "type:com.apple.twitter\nidentifier: NUMBERS-HERE\naccountDescription: @MYUSERNAME\nusername: MYUSERNAME\nobjectID: x-coredata://COREDATAHERE/Account/p19\nenabledDataclasses: {(\n)}\nenableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(\n)}\nproperties: {\n    fullName = \"First Last\";\n    \"user_id\" = USERIDHERE;\n}\nparentAccount: (null)\nowningBundleID:(null)"
)`

Comment: I guess you are retrieving it by `[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i]` ? am i correct?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I just did an nslog set to the array to get what I last posted.

Comment: What is at objectAtIndex:i, that same value will be given by my code fast enumearion one?

Answer (score 2):

You can't write `[arrayOfAccounts count]--`, this essentially expands to:

```
[arrayOfAccounts count] = [arrayOfAccounts count] - 1; // assigning to readonly
```

Instead, just use `[arrayOfAccounts count] - 1` (or fast enumeration).

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]-1; i++) { //...
```

Edit regarding `InvalidArgumentException`:

Assuming `arrayOfAccounts` contains `ACAccount` objects and not `NSString`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfAccounts count]-1; i++) { //...
    ACAccount * account = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:i];
    [chooseaccount addButtonWithTitle:[account userName]];
}
```

Comment: Tried this but got error `SInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ACAccount length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: What is the type of `arrayOfAccounts`?

Comment: It is ACAccount of type twitteraccount

Comment: If `arrayOfAccounts` is an `ACAccount` and NOT a `NSArray`, you don't have multiple user names to add to the action sheet... You can get the array of accounts using the `ACAccountStore accountsWithAccountType:` method.

Comment: I changed the loop according to what you had in the edit, and added `NSLog(@"%@", account.username);`  The tab bar controller never appeared, and the log only came back with one username.  If I remove the `-1` after the count in the loop, the log will return both user names that are in settings, but the tab bar controller never appears.

Comment: Ok, so the actionsheet is appearing, but only after about 25 seconds from performing the action.  See the OP for an edit of the code in entirety.

Comment: Your revised method works fine for me. How is `-(void)twitterAccess` being invoked? Maybe try `[chooseaccount showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`

Comment: It works fine in mine, just takes over 20 seconds to display the action sheet.

Comment: So, any suggestions for why it is taking over 20 seconds for action sheet to appear?

Comment: How is `-(void)twitterAccess` being called? From an `IBAction`?